# How to access my JSON code in this case

Tags: javascript

How to access the name and lastName in the following format in JavaScript:

```
images: [{"name":{"firstName":"Mike","lastName":"Brown"}}]
```

What I have tried, but no success:

```
images[0][name]//No success
images[0][name][firstName]//No success
```

Please let me know the right way to access them

Appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
images[0]['name'] 
images[0]['name']['firstName']
```

or

```
images[0].name
images[0].name.firstName
```

Answer (score 2):

```
images[0].name
images[0].name.firstName
```

You use `[]` notation when you're computing the property name or it's not a valid identifier, you use `.` when it's a literal identifier.

Comment: I don't like your explanation. If the property identifier is `foo bar` the `.` is not going to work because of the space. Basically: use a `.` if you can.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen It's not a valid identifier because of the space.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `var obj = { "foo bar": "foo" };` is allowed and valid. `obj["foo bar"]` gives `"foo"`. `obj.foo bar` gives a syntax error.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen And the reason you have to put quotes around it is because it's not an identifier.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, it's a property. Properties are never identifiers.

Comment: In `{ fooBar: 3 }` you can write it without quotes because it satisfies the syntax of an identifier.

Comment: I see what you're trying to say with _valid identifier_, it even catches cases like `var obj = { "function": "foo" }` but I feel like that's more of a happy coincidence.

Comment: @Frits: What do you mean by it catches cases like that? `var obj = { function: "foo" }` is actually valid. It's not a coincidence, that's how it is defined in the specification: http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5. `PropertyName` has to be `IdentifierName`, `StringLiteral` or `NumericLiteral`. And `IdentifierName` is defined here: http://es5.github.io/#x7.6. `Identifier` is actually a subset of `IdentifierName`. Maybe you are confusing the term "identifier" with "variable"?

Comment: He may be thinking of what IE does. It's more restrictive than required -- on several occasions I've been caught when using `{ class: "foo" }` in a literal (it comes up often when using jQuery to create elements); IE complains of a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. You need to provide string literals to the dictionary object:

```
images[0]['name']//No success
images[0]['name']['firstName']//No success
```